# How to create new column from combination of existing character and numeric columns?

Tags: r

My data is structured as follows:

```
 Name   Drill Movement Repetition    DV    
1 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          1   10   
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          1   12   
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          2   12   
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          2   9    
3 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          3   14   
3 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          3   12    
4 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            1   13  
4 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            1   17   
5 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            2   11   
5 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            2   15
```

I would like to add in a column `Trial` that contains a code for each unique combination of `Movement` and `Repetition`, such as:

```
 Name   Drill Movement Repetition    DV     Trial
1 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          1   10   D90_Sprint1
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          1   12   D90_Sprint1
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          2   12   D90_Sprint2 
2 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          2   9    D90_Sprint2 
3 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          3   14   D90_Sprint3 
3 RUTH 90_Turn   Sprint          3   12   D90_Sprint3 
4 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            1   13   D90_Walk1 
4 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            1   17   D90_Walk1 
5 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            2   11   D90_Walk2
5 RUTH 90_Turn   Walk            2   15   D90_Walk2
```

This takes into account the `Drill` which remains constant, along with `Name` - the `data.frame` only consists of Ruth's data for this drill. The `DV` is measured at least twice per `Movement` and `Repetition`.

Is it possible to do this?

My data frame is 10140 obs. so a quick solution would be ideal. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `paste0("D90_", df1$Movement, df1$Repetition)`

Comment: If you're not too concerned about the output format, it is essentially `interaction(dat[c("Drill","Movement","Repetition")])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
df1$Trial <- paste0("D90_", df1$Movement, df1$Repetition)
```

If '90' comes from the 'Drill' column

```
df1$Trial <- paste0("D", sub("_.*", "", df1$Drill), "_", df1$Movement, df1$Repetition)
```

Or with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("D%s_%s%d", sub("_.*", "", df1$Drill), df1$Movement, df1$Repetition)
#[1] "D90_Sprint1" "D90_Sprint1" "D90_Sprint2" "D90_Sprint2" "D90_Sprint3" "D90_Sprint3" "D90_Walk1"   "D90_Walk1"   "D90_Walk2"  
#[10] "D90_Walk2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste0()`:

```
df$Trial <- paste0(sub("_.*", "", df$Drill),
                   "_",
                   df$Movement,
                   df$Repetition)
```

The call to `sub()` extracts the `Drill` component of the final `Trial` string.